# Unity WebAPI: Unable to resolve individual types

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I have created a standalone WebAPI (no client) and have tried to start implementing DI using the Unity container for WebAPI.

However, when specifying my providers in the OAuthServerOptions (which depend on a custom token authentication service), I am unable to manually specify what they should resolve to.

If someone could point me as to where I am going wrong as it seems to work a bit differently than Unity with MVC.

**Unity Config:**

`.RegisterComponents()` is called in Startup.cs.

```
public static class UnityConfig
{
    public static void RegisterComponents()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        // These two are the ones which won't resolve!
        container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationTokenProvider, SimpleRefreshTokenProvider>();
        container.RegisterType<IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider, SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider>();

        container.RegisterType<ITokenAuthenticationManager, TokenAuthenticationManager>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

        // Some more type registrations which work fine...

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
    }
}
```

**Startup.Auth:**

This is where I am unable to manually resolve the providers...

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions { get; private set; }

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Some OWIN context setups...

        // Auth server setup
        OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider)),
            RefreshTokenProvider = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IAuthenticationTokenProvider)),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(timeSpan.TotalMinutes + 5),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };

        // Enable bearer tokens...
    }
}
```

**Startup:**

```
public partial class Startup
{  
     public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

            UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();     

            ConfigureAuth(app);

            WebApiConfig.Register(config);

            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }
    }
```

**SimpleAuthorizationServiceProvider:**

```
// Note: OAuthAuthoizationServiceProvider implements IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider

public class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    private ITokenAuthenticationManager tokenAuthenticationManager;

    public SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(ITokenAuthenticationManager tokenAuthenticationManager)
    {
        this.tokenAuthenticationManager = tokenAuthenticationManager;
    }
}
```

**SimpleRefreshTokenProvider:**

```
public class SimpleRefreshTokenProvider : IAuthenticationTokenProvider
{
    private ITokenAuthenticationManager tokenAuthenticationManager;

    public SimpleRefreshTokenProvider(ITokenAuthenticationManager tokenAuthenticationManager)
    {
        this.tokenAuthenticationManager = tokenAuthenticationManager;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know the startup.cs will be invoked first. And I see you don't register Unity in Startup.cs 
That means you can't find the concrete implementation. Let's try to register is before using it.

Comment: still no luck I'm afraid. I have updated the question code to reflect these changes too.

Comment: let's try with this : HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
  config.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(
      SelfHostWebApiOwin.UnityHelpers.GetConfiguredContainer()); SelfHostWebApiOwin.UnityHelpers.GetConfiguredContainer() is your container. Please let me know if it works